# Why Finder opens same folder each time i create new window by tapping finder icon in dock?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

I have created directory in my dropbox.
And i noticed that every time i have no windows of finder created and tap on finder icon in dock it creates new window with this new folder opened.
But my default folder set to another directory.
Also, if i press cmd+n or cmd+t it opens my default folder.
What can i do to fix this bug?

P.S. if i move this folder to another directory, bug disappears
if i change path to this folder (e.g. folderA/folderB/badfolder —> foldeRRA/folderB/badfolder), bugs disappears
if i delete this folder completely, and then recreate exactly same path, bug appears again.
Also, i used git and virtualenv there, if it is important.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by deleting com.apple.finder.plist
[tutorial for deleting finder.plist](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/finder.html)

But i still wondering why this have happened.